# InverseCDF gives $\infty$ error with an argument $1-t$ where t is very small

Tags: probability-or-statistics

InverseCDF works fine with the normal distribution quite far out on the right tail, but eventually I am getting an $\infty$ error. Thus

```
N[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], 1 - 9*10^-15]]
```

gives

```
7.66416
```

but

```
N[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], 1 - 9.1*10^-15]]
```

gives

```
∞
```

How can I avoid getting the infinity error?

Comment: You should use rational numbers (91*10^-16) rather than machine precision numbers in this case:  `N[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], 1 - 91*10^-16]]` gives 7.66275.  And don't be surprised if this question is closed because this is a common issue. See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#21155 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118797/machine-precision-and-arbitrary-precision.

Answer (score 5):

A series expansion helps to stabilize the calculation:

```
a[y_] = Assuming[0 < y < 1,
  FullSimplify[Normal[Series[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], 1-y], {y, 0, 1}]]]]
(*    Sqrt[-2*Log[y] - Log[-2*π*Log[2*π*y^2]]]    *)
```

Evaluation is now very stable even for small values of $y$:

```
a[9.1*10^-15]
(*    7.66047    *)

a[3.7*10^-81]
(*    19.0435    *)
```